# If I connect a battery to the vin pin on the arduino, will the 5V pin be activated?

Tags: arduino-mega

My wording might be a bit confusing, if I plug an 8 volt battery into Vin, will the arduino be powered and will the 5V pins work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's what the Vin pin is for: unregulated voltage or a voltage higher than 5V. Then the 5V pin will be at 5V, regulated by the on board regulator. You would only connect a source to the 5V pin if the source is already a regulated 5V.

Answer (score 1):

> - **VIN.** The input voltage to the Arduino board when it's using an external power source (as opposed to 5 volts from the USB connection or other regulated power source). You can supply voltage through this pin, or, if supplying voltage via the power jack, access it through this pin.

[source](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega)